# UICollectionView Centers Cell on Landscape only for Phone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, storyboard, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView that makes use of one cell per section.  It scrolls vertically.  I've made the collection view cell size 320X125 although I have played with width to no avail.

When on the iPhone in portrait mode the cell starts at the left of screen which is the desired behavior.  However, when I rotate the phone to landscape, the cell centers in the collection view.  On the iPad, however, it stays to the left in both orientations.

I would like the cell to stay stuck to the left side of the screen regardless of orientation.  How can this be accomplished?  While autolayout works for things inside the cell, there does not appear to be an autolayout that can be applied to the cell itself.

Comment: It would be nice if you could post more information (pictures of the storyboard, autolayout constraints, code, etc)

Comment: None of the code deals with placement.  As mentioned the cell itself takes no autolayout constraints so there are none to show.  This is probably more a question about cell behavior in a UICollectionView.  The only thing that seems to impact placement is to increase the size of the cell's width.  However, doing so would push the content off the screen in portrait mode.

Comment: What is the size (width) of the UICollectionView? What are the settings for margins/insets, inter-cell spacing, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by creating a second cell for the iPad.  So there is one for iPhone and the other iPad.  I then used:

`func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell`

Based on device orientation I set the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` I then used:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        let deviceType = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom

        if deviceType == .Phone
        {
            return CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.width, 170)
        }
        else
        {
            return CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.width, 400)
        }
    }
```

This resized the cell based on the phone or tablet.

As a last item, I used the following to redraw after the device was rotated:

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
    {
        coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition(nil) { (context) -> Void in
            self.collectionsView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```